# How does nuclear/radiation dye improve the quality of my bones' medical-imagery? What is the purpose of a bone scan?

Tags: procedure-purposes, dyes, bone-scan, nuclear-radiation

Yesterday, I thought I had went to the hospital for a CT-scan, but apparently my appointment was for a bone-scan (ordered by my orthopedic surgeon, who focuses on ankles).

I was redirected to the Nuclear-Medicine Department, and was first injected with a nuclear dye, and asked to come back several hours later. I was then handed with an official document for me to hand to any personnel or authority at a border crossing/airport since the radiation inside me would trigger nuclear alarms/triggers (had no idea that this existed). Then after the dye was dispersed throughout my body several hours later, I returned, and they put me in a machine (I think it was labelled SCENE) and it supposedly took images of my bones.

**1. How does the nuclear dye improve the quality of the images that they acquired?**

**2.How is a bone-scan any better than a CT-scan? Is it a new technology?**

**3.What purposes does it fulfill? (I had x-rays for the Dr. 3 weeks prior, and I have arthritis, but why would a bone-scan be necessary)?**